# How NaN==NaN returns false?

Tags: javascript

```
NaN==NaN
```

returns false in javascripts. i want to know some clear explanation.

```
typeof NaN is number

Number == Number is return true
```

Then why `NaN==NaN` is false. Thanks advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Number == Number is return true*"?

Comment: read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: `Number` == `Number`, you are comparing the Number object. Ofcourse it's going to return `true`. It's similar to something like `Math == Math` and so on.. also, `typeof number` returns you the data type of the `NaN`, that is not the same as the Object `Number`